# How do I find current consumed by circuit designed on surface mount PCB without damaging PCB?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, current-measurement, surface-mount, load

I have a circuit designed on PCB, and components (resistors, capacitors, diodes, microcontrollers, etc.) are all surface mount. I want to find the total current consumed by this circuit. I have traced the schematic of the circuit completely, and the circuit and MCU operate on 3.3 VDC.

The supply 3.3 VDC is generated through AC 240 RMS, then half-wave rectifier, then filter capacitor and finally 3.3 V regulators.

There is also a port left open for the battery but no battery is attached. I want to make the circuit portable so that it can work without direct supply, which is why I need current consumption of circuit to estimate the battery specifications.

I can't break any connections to measure the current using DMM, because it's a layered PCB and I am afraid I might damage it.

Is there any other way to find the total load that circuit has or current it consumes?

Note: MCU has the normal operating current of 2.4-5.4 mA.

Comment: If the circuit is line powered, the exact current really doesn't matter that much.  You can get a rough idea with an AC mains meter you plug it into.  If it's too small to measure with that, then it's also small enough that you really don't *need* to know exactly what it is, and if you still want to badly enough, then you can afford to buy a cheap hot air tool and sacrifice one copy of the design to measurement or learn to use it well enough that you'd don't even damage that copy.  Milliwatts matter when you run on batteries, not on the mains.

Comment: When people speak of idle mains-powered appliances unjustifiably wasting power, they're talking about fractions of a watt large enough to measure with a plug in meter.

Comment: If I can measure (which I can) the current from AC mains, then it would mean that this will be the current consumed by a circuit (DC circuit working at 3.3 Vdc)?

Comment: No, the power drawn at the mains input will be a little more than that consumed by the DC side.  But you've failed to state a justifiable reason *why* you need to know, so there's no argument as to which current matters until you can make a sound argument why *either* current matters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thank you for suggestion, actually, i need to install a battery for this circuit, for that i think i need to estimate current of circuit to estimate mAh of battery..

Comment: Pretty obviously you can't install a battery until you find a way to power the circuit with DC.   Once you've done that, measure the current consumed from the DC supply.  Feeding the existing mains supply from an inverter powered from batteries is probably a grossly inefficient idea, if the overall power consumption is as low as you are implying it is or low enough for the plug in meter not to give a fair representation.

Comment: i understand, in my case the pcb is already built, and there is also a connection for battery in pcb (it was left for purpose that circuit keeps running even the AC mains is off, though it was not needed before, so no battery was attached, but now i want to make circuit portable means without direct supply). Plus this is locally made PCB and the seller didn't have specs about it themselves..

Comment: The belatedly revealed presence of a battery input connector makes your entire question moot.  Unplug it from the mains, hook up a battery or bench supply with some clip leads and an ammeter in series and measure it already.  Of course if you don't know what the DC input voltage should be, this conversion project is perhaps not one you should be attempting.

Comment: Yes, But what kind of battery? I tried to do this with 2/3AA 3.6 V battery, and not all the functionalities of the circuit were on, I mean some LEDs were so dull and some were off. I am afraid I might damage the PCB I try just any battery, so I was hoping to find the current, then apply appropriate battery...

Comment: It sounds like you do not have the experience to perform this conversion in a safe manner.  Please desist before you encounter a problem more serious than non-operation, and instead purchase an alternate version of the item already configured for battery power.

Comment: Plus, i asked if there is a way to find the current of this kind of circuit, i don't think, my purpose of finding the curent is important for it to be answered..

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Sir if i had experience and skill or someone close to guide me, why would i post my question here..

Comment: A question here will not be able to provide the missing information to do this conversion in a safe manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way to measure currents on PCB where all components are already integrated (AC, transformer, secondary coil, diode bridge, regulator) is to make a narrow trace cut between the regulator and the rest of the circuit, and measure the current either by a fixed-range DMM, or placing a current-sense resistor (say, 0.1 Ohms SMT 0805) across the cut, and measure small voltage across it. Then you either leave the sensing resistor to continue to operate your device, or restore the trace continuity with a solder bridge.

(Suggestion: you can find various small-ohm chip resistors on all broken hard drive electronics or old dead CD-ROMs.)

Comment: That’s also one of the reasons why 0ohm resistors were invented. Many of my designs have a few of those at that precise location.

Comment: @BetaEngineer, if you want to use the battery input, it is safe to assume your regulator as linear (LDO), and use the battery voltage about 2V above your 3.3 V power rail. 4 AA battery should do the job. In this way you don't need to cut anything, just measure the current from 6-V battery.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, yes, zero-ohm are good things, in industrial world it is called DFT, "design for test". Whoever fails to do this upfront on first board iteration go out of business quickly.